What is the best way to subdivide a simplex?
Let $\Delta^k$ be the $k$-simplex, embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$ in the usual way so that all edges have length $\sqrt{2}$.  For $k\leq 2$, there are obvious ways to subdivide $\Delta^k$ into $2^k$ congruent copies of the simplex $\frac{1}{2}\Delta^k$, with edges of length $1/\sqrt{2}$.  For $k=3$ the theory of scissors congruence shows that this is not possible, essentially because the Dehn invariant has scaling behaviour different from that of the volume.  We can instead cut off $4$ copies of $\frac{1}{2}\Delta^3$ adjacent to the vertices, which leaves a regular octahedron, then join each face of the octahedron to the barycentre, giving $8$ more tetrahedra with some edges of length $1/\sqrt{2}$ and others of length $1/2$.
For general $k$, if we just use barycentric subdivision, the longest edges (from the barycentre to one of the original vertices) have length $\sqrt{\frac{k}{k+1}}$, whereas the shortest edges (from the barycentre to the barycentre of a face) have length $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}}$, so the ratio is $k$.
We could instead do edgewise subdivision, so the subdivided complex has vertices $e_{ij}=(e_i+e_j)/2$, and there is an edge from $e_{ij}$ to $e_{kl}$ whenever $i\leq k\leq l\leq j$. In this case all edges have length $1$ or $1/\sqrt{2}$.  This is much more regular, but the construction is not invariant under the action of the symmetric group $\Sigma_{k+1}$.
Are there other schemes, preferably invariant under the symmetric group, that divide $\Delta^k$ into $k$-simplices that are reasonably close to being congruent?  Or is there some conceptual reason why one should not expect this to be possible?

Maybe you should first subdivide the simplex barycentrically into $(k+1)!$ congruent pieces, and then choose some subdivision of one of those pieces into simplices that are "reasonably close to being congruent". (And then cut up each of those pieces in the same way.)
